# how do I encrypt this data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

how do I encrypt this data so that it is not visible, my case is when the data is updated, this data appears, how do I fix it? I update it using ajax

[image]

Comment: why would you need to encrypt that?

Comment: is there any suggestion for this ?, i just want this data not visible only, 
or this data can be encrypted, thanks friend

Comment: @WildanFathurRohman What specifically are you trying to protect against?  Who are you trying to hide this data from, and why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you just want to deter people from being able to read your client/server communication in the dev console/http inspector so that they must
jump through some hoops right?

You're basically asking how to create your own data format for client/server communication. The solution is actually the same way JSON/XML/BSON handlers are created. When you have an object in Javascript you serialize it to JSON right? Let's say your format is called `WFR`. Create a javascript function that serializes/deserializes `WFR` and a server side implementation that processes it and responds in the same format. Easy.

I don't know what your server side tech is, but an article like this might get you started conceptually. https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/september/custom-input-and-output-serializers-in-aspnet-core/

Comment: yes that's my goal, thank you friends, but is there any other solution that you can send besides that link?, i using ajax and laravel.

Comment: It's trivial to get around this.  Any time spent on trying to encrypt data sent to the client is time wasted, and isn't remotely any sense of security.  -1

Comment: is it ok that this data is not encrypted? Do you think?,What do you think, should it be encrypted or not? Is it safe if not encryption?, i dont know about this friend, give me solution

Answer (score -1):

Use https and move the sensitive data to your body request/header instead of query param will solve your issue